# Jest mocking implementation of a method accepting callback of third party

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am using Nest + Cognito to authenticate a user on an application, I have a method inside my Authentication service that I am trying to test/mock which is:

```js
async cognitoRegister(userPool: CognitoUserPool, {
    name,
    password,
    email
}: AuthRegisterInput): Promise < ISignUpResult > {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return userPool.signUp(
            name,
            password,
            [new CognitoUserAttribute({
                Name: 'email',
                Value: email
            })],
            null,
            (err, result) => {
                if (!result) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(result);
                }
            },
        );
    });
}
```

Here the **signUp** function is a method coming from the third party CognitoUserPool which I managed to mock using module name mapper inside my package.json, here it is:

```js
function CognitoUserPool(data) {
  const { UserPoolId, ClientId } = data;
  this.userPoolId = UserPoolId;
  this.clientId = ClientId;
  this.getCurrentUser = jest.fn().mockReturnValue("cognitouserpool");
  // This method
  this.signUp = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true);
}
module.exports = CognitoUserPool;
```

and is implementation:

```js
module.exports = {
  CognitoUserPool: jest.fn().mockImplementation(require("./CognitoUserPool")),
};
```

Since the signUp method accept a callback which is responsible of giving me a result/reject value I should somehow mock it otherwise Jest is giving me a timeout error since the implementation returns a Promise that stays in a pending state.

Basically I am trying to mock a function of this kind:

```js
const foo = (arg1, cb) => {
    ...do something...
}

const bar = (arg1, arg2...) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return foo(arg1, (err, result) => {
            if (!result) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(result)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Here is what I am trying to do inside my test:

```js
it("should register a cognito user", async () => {
  const mockedCongitoUserPool = new CognitoUserPool({
    UserPoolId: authConfig.userPoolId,
    ClientId: authConfig.clientId,
  });
  const result = await service.cognitoRegister(mockedCongitoUserPool, {
    ...mockedUser,
  });
  console.log(result);
});
```

I also have a git for that can be helpful:

[Main service link](https://github.com/frivolta/cv-generator-api/blob/master/src/auth/auth.service.ts)

[Mocked third party implementation link](https://github.com/frivolta/cv-generator-api/tree/master/src/__mocks__/amazon-cognito-identity-js)

[Tests implementation link](https://github.com/frivolta/cv-generator-api/blob/master/src/auth/auth.service.spec.ts)

Any help here is appreciated <3, ask for any further explanation I really need some help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a static resolution, your mocked module should declare an implementation like the following instead of just a return value:

```
this.signUp = jest.fn().mockImplementation((name, pwd, attlist, something, cb) => {
  process.nextTick(cb(null, 'signedup!'))
});
```

Here `process.nextTick` just simulates async, but you could just call `cb(null, 'some result')` as well if you don't care.

If you want to dynamically control the callback resolution, you could override the default mocked implementation depending on your scenario:

```
let cup: CognitoUserPool;
beforeAll(() => { // or maybe beforeEach, depends on what the mock keeps/does
  cup = new CognitoUserPool({ userPoolId: 'fakeUserPoolId', ClientId: 'fakeClientId' });
});
it('should resolve', async () => {
  const expected = { any: 'thing' };
  cup.signUp.mockImplementation((a, b, c, d, cb) => cb(null, expected));
  await expect(service.cognitoRegister(cup, mockedUser)).resolves.toBe(expected);
});
it('should fail', async () => {
  const expected = new Error('boom!');
  cup.signUp.mockImplementation((a, b, c, d, cb) => cb(expected));
  await expect(service.cognitoRegister(cup, mockedUser)).rejects.toThrow(expected);
});
```

Comment: yep, this one, just started with jest, was trying to use mockResolvedValue for no reason tnx